# Rename blender source files and get them to relink

Tags: video

I'm using blender as a video editor and would like to rename all the source files to some logical names (rather than Data/time names).  However, I suspect if I do this the links to the edited version will be lost.  What is the best way to rename the files so as to minimize the pain of relinking all the strip sources?

Comment: Hello :). I think Blender only identifies files by their filename. So if you change the name outside of Blender, you'll need to relink the file.

Comment: Jachym - yes it seems to do this - I'm looking for a clever way not to have to link a dozen files if I change the names